django instance.add() is not working on new m2m field added
Difference between Code 1 and Code 2 given below is that industry and dindustry fields are interchanged.
While Code 1 works fine Code 2 doesn't update the database. Can someone please help.....
Note:

Table was altered and dindustry was newly created.
No migration issues, I am able to add records to both industry and dindustry through django Admin

Code 1:
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Company.dindustry.through)
def video_category_changed(sender, instance, action, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == "post_add":
        sectors = Sectors.objects.filter(id__in=pk_set)
        roots = set()
        for sector in sectors:
            root = sector.get_root()
            if not instance.industry.filter(id=root.id).exists():
                instance.industry.add(root)
                print('data added')

Code 2:
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Company.industry.through)
def video_category_changed(sender, instance, action, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == "post_add":
        sectors = Sectors.objects.filter(id__in=pk_set)
        roots = set()
        for sector in sectors:
            root = sector.get_root()
            if not instance.dindustry.filter(id=root.id).exists():
                instance.dindustry.add(root)
                print('data added')

My model is as below:
class Company(MPTTModel):
    industry = models.ManyToManyField(Sectors, related_name='relatedname_industry', blank=True)
    dindustry = models.ManyToManyField(Sectors, related_name='relatedname_dindustry', blank=True)

class Sectors(MPTTModel):
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

It works well on one m2m field but doesn't work on another m2m field in the same table

What are industry and dindustry, although not impossible, it is not very common to have two M2Ms to the same model.

Also note that the two signals can trigger each other resulting in an (almost) infinite loop.
